# SequelizeJs: order by term

Tags: node.js, sqlite, orm, sql-order-by, sequelize.js

I'm using [sequelizejs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) for SQLite in nodejs. I try to get a sql like:

```
 SELECT
  id,
  description,
  created_at,
  postponed,
  done_at
FROM tasks
WHERE done_at IS NULL
ORDER by (id+postponed),postponed,id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

the problem is the term `id+postponed` in the `OREDR BY`
I tried this:

```
Task.find({
          where: ["done_at is not null"],
          order: [["(id+postponed)", "ASC"], ["postponed", "ASC"], ["id", "ASC"]],
          limit: 1
        }).then(...)
```

But the the query becomes: `ORDER BY task.(task_id+postponed) ASC, task.postponed ASC, task.task_id ASC`

Do someone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution on my own:

```
Task.find({
    where: ["done_at is not null"],
    order: '(id+postponed),postponed,id ASC',
    limit: 1
}).then(...)
```

That isn't perfect but works for me.